# Which web language can be used for data mining or web crawling

Tags: data-mining, web-crawler

if I want to build a complex webiste like google news , which gathers data from oher websites.
like data mining , crawling. In which language should i build the website.

Currently i know only PHP. Can i do that in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is a great language for both of these tasks. I can't easily name all the available packages out there, but the first that come to mind for web crawling are [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html). [Orange](http://www.ailab.si/orange/) and [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) implement several data mining algorithms.

Comment: +1. I agree. I use Python for scraping and I specifically use BeautifulSoup and sometimes xml.dom

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to build two apps, something to crawl the web and store the data in a database, then a website to display the collected data. I would use Perl to crawl the web for it's good string manipulation features.

Comment: ca i do that in python as well . i am confused what to opt for python or perl . Becaus i am also thinking of applying some intelligent algos using python like google does

Comment: One thing also . so it means it is not necesaary to have one script or application doing ecevrything. i can have combination of many

Comment: If you're new to either language, I'd go with Python. It has a much simpler syntax, and has a larger community and collection of libraries. You'll find Perl's syntax is much more complicated without adding any extra value, and its userbase is shrinking because people are switching to newer languages like Python or Ruby.